# analytic expression of eigenvalue of A.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

The following square matrix of order $N$ coming out of discretization of pde. Now I want to compute the analytic expression of eigenvalue of $A.$

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
-2&2&0&0&0&0&0\\
1&-2&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&-2&1&0&0&0\\
\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots\\
0&0&0&1&-2&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&-2&1\\
0&0&0&0&0&1&-2
\end{pmatrix}$$

The problem creates $a_{1,2}$, if $a_{1,2}=1$ we get the eigenvalue by Toeplitz matrices structure.

My thought: Let $\lambda$ be the eigenvalue of $A$, then we have $AU=\lambda U.$ From that we can get $u_{i-1}-2u_i +u_{i+1}=\lambda u_i  ,\  \text{for}\, i=2,2,...,N-1$ and $-2u_{1}+u_{2}=\lambda u_1 $
and $u_{N-1}-2u_{N}=\lambda u_N $

so we have the recurrence relation $u_{i+1}=(\lambda +2)u_i -u_{i-1}  ,\  \text{for}\, i=2,2,...,N-1$

Let $u_i=r^{i}$ then we have $r^2-(\lambda+2)r+1=0$ and from that I can get get the eigen vector representation of the form $\alpha r^i+\beta r^{-i}$. But I could not find the value of $\alpha,\beta$ using other two equation and so I havent get the eigenvalue.

Is there a bettere way to get the analytic expression of eigenvalue?

If I use recurrance relation to get the eigenvalue, how I find out $\alpha, \beta$?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the $(1,2)$ entry meant to be $2$? Just curious.

Comment: the $(1,2)$ entry is $2$ as given in the matrix.

Comment: To put it a bit differently: You start with a Toeplitz matrix and introduce a rank-one perturbation. Specifically, if $A_0$ is the appropriate Toeplitz matrix, then you've got $A=A_0+e_1 e_2^\top$. To my eye that suggests studying $A(\lambda)=A_0+\lambda e_1 e_2^\top$, and maybe doing something in the vein of the [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula).

Comment: (Though, probably $\lambda$ isn't a good choice given its frequent use for denoting eigenvalues. $z$ would perhaps be a more apt choice.)

Answer (score 1):

I'll take the liberty of writing $A_N$ to denote the $N \times N$ version of the concerned matrix.

We are interested in the eigenvalues of $A_N$, i.e. the roots of the characteristic polynomial $p_N(\lambda) = |A_N - \lambda I_N|$. For simplicity, let's introduce the variable $t = 2 + \lambda$ such that
$$
p_N(t) =
\begin{vmatrix}
-t & 2 & 0 & \dots & \\
1 & -t & 1 & \dots & \\
& & \ddots & & \\
& \dots & 1 & -t & 1 \\
& \dots & 0 & 1 & -t
\end{vmatrix}.
$$
Expanding this determinant about the final row leads us to the observation that $p_N(t) = -t p_{N-1}(t) - p_{N-2}(t)$. By explicitly computing $p_2$ and $p_3$ and working backwards we can assign values to $p_1$ and $p_0$, resulting in the recurrence relation
\begin{align}
p_N &= -t p_{N-1} - p_{N-2}, \\
p_0 &= 2, \\
p_1 &= -t.
\end{align}

The solution takes the form
$$
p_N(t) = c_+ r_+^N + c_- r_-^N,
$$
where $c_\pm$ are constants soon to be determined and $r_\pm = \frac{-t \pm \sqrt{t^2 - 4}}{2}$ are the roots of the polynomial $r^2 + t r + 1$ (i.e. the characteristic polynomial of the recurrence). Considering the cases $N=0$ and $N=1$ and using the known values for $p_0$ and $p_1$ we find that $c_+ = c_- = 1$. Thus, we have
$$
p_N(t) = \left( \frac{-t + \sqrt{t^2 - 4}}{2} \right)^N + \left( \frac{-t - \sqrt{t^2 - 4}}{2} \right)^N.
$$
We now make the substitution $t = -2 \cos{(\theta)}$ so that our expression simplifies to
$$
p_N(\theta) = (\cos{(\theta)} + i \sin{(\theta)})^N + (\cos{(\theta)} - i \sin{(\theta)})^N = e^{i N \theta} + e^{-i N \theta} = 2 \cos{(N \theta)}.
$$
Now, recall that we are looking for $N$ eigenvalues of $A_N$, i.e. for $N$ roots of $p_N$. We find them where $\cos{(N \theta)} = 0$:
\begin{align}
\theta &= \frac{\pi}{N} \left( k + \frac{1}{2} \right) \\
\Rightarrow t &= -2 \cos{ \left( \frac{\pi}{N} \left( k + \frac{1}{2} \right) \right)} \\
\Rightarrow \lambda &= -2 \left( 1 + \cos{ \left( \frac{\pi}{N} \left( k + \frac{1}{2} \right) \right)} \right),
\end{align}
for $k = 0, \dots, N-1$.